# Connecting additional devices using the cable between modem and router

Tags: router, modem, cable

The network infrastructure in my parents' house is rather inconvenient. The modem is in the basement and the wireless router is in the attic. The only device connected via cable is my HTPC in the living room. I'd like to get a NAS for the HTPC, but unfortunately there is really no room anymore in the living room, so I'd like to put in in the basement, next to the modem.

The modem is running in single-user-mode, so the router is dialing in. There's a LAN cable connected to the modem and the internet/modem port of the router.

Would it actually be possible to connect additional devices to the network using this cable (with a hub or switch), or would I have to use another LAN port of the router*?

* Either putting the NAS next to the router in the attic, or installing another cable.

Comment: Put the NAS in the attic, next to the router

Comment: router in the attic doing the NAT? is your HTPC connected directly to the router in the attic?  Are you opposed to using 2 Switches? one in the attic and one in the basement, and running vlan trunking between the 2 of them?) so you can have the modem traffic in 1 vlan and internal lan traffic in the other?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if you connect it to the cable going from modem to router. I has to be a LAN port from the router if you want it to be part of that network.